# Return error or ternary operator in react js component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
  let image = <GlobalData response={imageSize} />;
  if (isSpinnerOpened) {
    image = (
      <Backdrop className={classes.backdrop} open={isSpinnerOpened}>
        <CircularProgress />
        <p>Loading Image File ...</p>
      </Backdrop>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      {error ? <Typography >Uh oh! No file found </Typography> : (
        <>
          {image}
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

I am trying to refactor this code. I do not want to use let. Is there any chance to return first the Typography if there is an error and if not to return the backdrop if isSpinnerOpened=true and if isSpinnerOpened=false to return the image. Something like:

```
const image = (
      <Backdrop className={classes.backdrop} open={isSpinnerOpened}>
        <CircularProgress />
        <p>Loading Image File ...</p>
      </Backdrop>
    );

return (
 if (error) {
   <Typography >Uh oh! No file found </Typography>
 } else {
   isSpinnerOpened : {image} ? <GlobalData response={imageSize} /> 
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without nesting the conditional operator (which can make things hard to read), use `if`/`else` with `return`s on the different lines:

```
if (error) {
  return <Typography >Uh oh! No file found </Typography>;
}
return !isSpinnerOpened
  ? null
  : (
      <Backdrop className={classes.backdrop} open={isSpinnerOpened}>
        <CircularProgress />
        <p>Loading Image File ...</p>
      </Backdrop>
    );
```

It'd be *possible* to just use the conditional operator here, but I don't think it's a great idea:

```
return error
  ? <Typography >Uh oh! No file found </Typography>
  : !isSpinnerOpened
    ? null
    : (
        <Backdrop className={classes.backdrop} open={isSpinnerOpened}>
          <CircularProgress />
          <p>Loading Image File ...</p>
        </Backdrop>
      );
```